# Authenticating user/password against Active Directory using ASP.NET Identity + own database (custom asp.net identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, asp.net-identity

I have implemented custom asp.net identity with database first approach. I have implemented token based implementation using OWIN.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<OVT_UserEntities>(() => new OVT_UserEntities());
app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserManager<User, int>>(
    (IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager<User, int>> options, IOwinContext context) =>
        new UserManager<User, int>(new UserStore(context.Get<OVT_UserEntities>())));

// Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    Provider = new OVTApplicationOAuthProvider(
        "self", () => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<User, int>>()),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/account/authorize"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
});
```

OVT_UserEntities is my custom db context which will validate the entered username with my own database.

now i want to do active directory authentication for organizational users account.

How can i implement both database  asp.net identity authentication + active directory implementation in asp.net identity  authentcation.

if the user enters his creditentials,  first i will check in database ,if it's not available then will go for active directory for further checking. if is avail in AD(active directory) then will redirect some other page by getting some tokens.

any references would be appreciated.